# Get Facebook Friends Possible 2020

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**All the answers that was available are too old** tried different ways but not able to get any information related to facebook logged in user friends.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: loginScreen) { (result, error) in
            if (result?.token != nil) {
                self.didLoginWithFacebook()
            }
}
```

the above set "**user_friends**" permission is not getting asked from the user and also not coming back in granted or denied permission.

And also using

```
let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath:"me/friends", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,last_name,first_name,picture"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)
    graphRequest.start { (connection, result, error) in
        guard let result = result as? [String:String] else{
            print("Facebook request user error")
            return
        }
        
    }
```

returning empty data fields

**I want to know is it even possible to get friends or not ?**

**Even we don't get friends after asking the user for permission ?**

Getting error when trying to login with admin user
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

According to

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

This api returns only

> Represents a collection of Users who are friends of the app User. Only
> friends who have installed the app and who have granted the app the
> user_friends permission will be included.

So, if You don't have any friends who also installed your app and granted friends permission -> response still be empty

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I got the point thanks but I wast to know I am sending "user_friends" permission but it now asking me for this permission any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

- Try with an app admin, regular users will not be able to use the permission if it is not approved by Facebook yet
- There is a missing apostrophe in your code, right after `user_friends`:

  permissions: ["public_profile", "email","user_friends"...

Comment: my app is still in development phase, it would not be able for facebook team to test it, so do we need to add this functionality after our first release ?

Comment: no, you can already use it, but it will only work for users with a role in the app, see the first point of my answer.

Comment: getting user_friends permission error when trying to login as an admin

Comment: got it thanks o put the app in distribution mode and it was not reviewed yet thats the reason getting the issue